# Send Messages Between Two Applications

Tags: vb.net, tcp, named-pipes

I need to send string messages between applications (many clients and one server).

When I tried using PostMessage/WndProc, then my message got split up in strange portions (I used this solution: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Send_string_by_message.aspx). So that was a no go.

Second I tried using Pipes, but couldn't make it work with multiple clients.

Third I tried using TCPIP, but couldn't make that work too.

My question:

What is the best (easiest) solution to achieve this?

Comment: Avoid inventing that wheel, WCF was made to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client/Server Applications usually work great with TCP/IP.

But as an alternative to TCP/IP I could also suggest .NET Remoting.

There are a lot of examples out there.

Example:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Remoting_HelloWorld.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Best approach would be **WCF**.

It supports so **many scenarios**. I have used it in many different situations.

Two applications on **same computer** or on **separate computers** or **client server** scenarios or **web apps**, you can implement them easily.

I used `NetNamedPipeBindin`, for connecting **2 application on the same machine**.

**MSDN** has many resources about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx